# issue with making a call using fetch and jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, fetch

*My goal here is to get the location of bikes from a bike-sharing company's API.
I did Steps 1 and 2 using Postman. but ill try to integrate it into my code once I get the hang of it.

1. The first step is to verify your email and generate an Auth token. This requires only a verifiable email address. Make a POST request to https://web.spin.pm/api/v1/magic_links with the body:
   `{"email": "sampleemail@gmail.com"}`
2. From there, you will need to find the token within your email. This token needs to be sent with a POST request to
   https://web.spin.pm/api/v1/auth_tokens with the body:

```
{
    "grant_type": "magic_link",
    "magic_link": {
        "email": "<email>",
        "token": "<token>"
    }
}
```

This request returns a JSON that looks like this: `{"jwt":"eyJ0eXAiOiJ.....cXVLw","refreshToken":"2cb07....bab5030","existingAccount":false}`

3. To get the position of vehicles so a GET-Request to https://web.spin.pm/api/v3/vehicles?lng=-77.0146489&lat=38.8969363&distance=&mode= User Header Authorization: Bearer  to Authenticate and use the jwt-Token we got from the Auth request.

You will get something like this as return JSON `{"vehicles":[{"lat":37.69247,"lng":-122.46595,"last4":"3595","vehicle_type":"bicycle","batt_percentage":null,"rebalance":null}, … ]}`

Step 3 is done using (async/awit function) using fetch where I am having the problem with. I copy-pasted the jwt in my .env file and set up the proper headers.
I get a 401 response when making the call. when I tested step 3 using postman everything seems to work fine.
I have attached a screenshot of the error in this post. Hopefully its more clear, Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    require('dotenv').config();

    async function getBikes()
                {
                    const lat = '38.897574612438575';
                    const lng = '-77.01855164084469';
                    const api_url = `https://web.spin.pm/api/v3/vehicles?lng=${lng}&lat=${lat}&distance=&mode=`;
                    const jwt_key = process.env.BERER_KEY;
                
                    try{
                
                       
                        const config = { method: 'GET',
                                        headers: {json: {
                                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                            'Authorization': 'Bearer'+ jwt_key
                                         } },
                                        rejectUnauthorized: false
                                       };
                        
                        const response = await fetch(api_url,config );
                        const data = await response.json(); //response.json()  //headers //.jwt; //response.json()
                        if (response.ok) 
                        {
                            console.log("STATUS CODE IS: "+response.status);
                            console.log('My JWT:', response);
                            return data;
                        } 
                        else{
                            console.log("something went wrong ");  
                            console.log("STATUS CODE IS: "+ response.status);
                            console.log( response);
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                  
                }
                
                
                const y = getBikes();
                console.log(y)
            

    BEARER_KEY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2V
```

Comment: 401 unauthorized means literally what it says. Authorization failed. Your issue is likely with `const jwt_key = process.env.BERER_KEY` Edit: Oh.. look at that it seams you spelled `BEARER_KEY` wrong

Comment: thanks for the fast response. im using the exact token saved in the .env file to make a get request on postman and i get the correct response without a problem with authorization. i just cant figure our what else might be causing that issue.

Comment: You spelled "BEARER" wrong.

Comment: And/or you need a space.. `'Authorization': 'Bearer'+ jwt_key` should be `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt_key`

Comment: Either way, how can we tell? You haven't given us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sorry, still having the same issue after the fix

Comment: Give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we'll try to help. Until then.. Good luck!

Comment: thank you ill try to rephrase the question

Comment: You can try exporting the `code > Generate code snippets` from postman to see the request you are sending is missing what, assuming the request is working in postman

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Thanks that worked